# ¿Cómo puedo sacar la provincia seleccionada en la opción de un formulario en un alert de javascript?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Quisiera saber quien me puede ayudar con el siguiente código, tengo un formulario en el cual quisiera lograr que la variable resultado nunca contenga el valor undefined porque ahora siempre está conteniendo undefined y no puedo sacar el resultado de la provincia seleccionada actualmente. Me serviría de mucha ayuda que alguién me dijera qué puedo hacer para conseguir mostrarlo. Un saludo y muchas gracias.

```js
const provincias = document.querySelector("#provincias");

var resultado;

provincias.addEventListener("onchange", (event) => {

    resultado = `Ha seleccionado: ${event.target.value}`;
    console.log(resultado);

});

const button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert(this.resultado);
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <label for="provincias">Selecciona la provincia</label>
    <select name="provincias" id="provincias">
        <option value="La Coruña">La Coruña</option>
        <option value="Lugo">Lugo</option>
        <option value="Ourense">Ourense</option>
        <option value="Pontevedra">Pontevedra</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Consultar información" id="button">
</form>
```

Comment: Excelente primera pregunta! Bien expuesta y con el código necesario para reproducir el problema. Me he tomado la libertad de convertir el código a un fragment o snippet ejecutable para poder reproducir el problema fácilmente, puedes revertir o [edit] si así lo consideras

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que en `provincias.addEventListener("onchange", (event) => {` has escrito `onchange`, cuando en realidad el nombre del evento es `change`, así que simplemente cambia eso por eso otro. Antes ese evento no estaba funcionando y no actualizaba el valor de `resultado`.

```js
const provincias = document.querySelector("#provincias");

var resultado;

provincias.addEventListener("change", (event) => {

    resultado = `Ha seleccionado: ${event.target.value}`;
    console.log(resultado);

});

const button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert(this.resultado);
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <label for="provincias">Selecciona la provincia</label>
    <select name="provincias" id="provincias">
        <option value="La Coruña">La Coruña</option>
        <option value="Lugo">Lugo</option>
        <option value="Ourense">Ourense</option>
        <option value="Pontevedra">Pontevedra</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Consultar información" id="button">
</form>
```

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de añadir un "snippet" (Se crea pulsando Ctrl + M cuando estás escribiendo una respuesta) con la corrección que mencionaste, espero que no moleste. Puedes editar o revertir mi cambio si así te parece

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#">

    <label for="provincias">Selecciona la provincia</label>

    <select name="provincias" id="provincias" onchange="MuestraProvincias()">

        <option value="La Coruña">La Coruña</option>
        <option value="Lugo">Lugo</option>
        <option value="Ourense">Ourense</option>
        <option value="Pontevedra">Pontevedra</option>

    </select>

    <input type="button" value="Consultar información" id="button">

</form>

<script>

var provincias;
var resultado;

function MuestraProvincias()
{
    provincias = document.getElementById("provincias");
    resultado = provincias.options[provincias.selectedIndex].text;

    button = document.querySelector("#button");
    
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {

        alert(this.resultado);

    });
}

</script>
```

Prueba este código.